# Creating a timed pause in batch, hiding and closing a non-batch program from batch

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I've created a program that I'd like to put in my start up routine,but It doesn't work right.

What I WANT it to do: Run my VBScript that says "Hello, the system is running well. You look quite handsome today." then start playing "I'm Sexy And I know it" hidden after the end of the VBScript.

What it does: Starts the VBScript, then immediatly starts Sexy and I know it in a new window that goes in front of everything else.

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
title GLaDOS
start c:\users\85564\desktop\GLaDOS.vbs
pause
Start C:\users\85564\desktop\Nicolas\fun\Musack\LMFAO-Sexy-and-I-Know-It.mp3
```

GLaDOS.vbs is the name of the VBScript that greets me. The Pause is so that it doesn't superimpose on the music. Line two renames the window to "GLaDOS". Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm fluent in English, Spanish, TI-83+Basic, and I'm working on learning Batch/VBScript.

Comment: What is it that's not working right?  You don't want Media Player showing a window?

Comment: @carey I don't want media player to show a window,I want it to start AFTER the VBS finishes running, and if possible, terminate the media player after the song is over.

Answer (score 1):

To create a timed pause in batch you can use `ping` like this:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11
```

There is a second delay which is why you need 11 pings and not 10 :)

You can read more about this [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php)

If you want to close media player after the song has finished you could ping pause the length of the song and then use:

```
taskkill /im wmplayer.exe /f
```

If you want to hide media player, in your vbscript use this:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("audiofilepath"), 0, True
```

This will work on XP and below as well without the need to install commands separately such as `choice`.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
choice /N /T 10 /D Y
```

This will pause the script for 10 seconds.